# Add Data Labels to Plotly Bullet Chart in R

Tags: r, label, plotly

I am following an example [here](https://moderndata.plot.ly/bullet-charts-in-r-using-plotly/) to create bullet charts in R, the last part I am stuck on is trying to add data labels to each of my data elements.

I thought this would be straight forward using text='' but the labels do not display and the code runs without error.

I would like to add a label and the inside end of both the inner and outer bar charts.

I believe it may have something to do with using attach & detatch but I am not exactly sure.  Any assistance is much appreciated.

UPDATE: Adding sample data for reference:

```
    library(plotly)
    library(dplyr)
    library(readxl)

    # Read data
    zz <- "name distance    office
name1   3200    3900
name2   3000    6900
name3   1700    5900
name4   1500    3500
name5   1200    2700
name6   1000    3700
name7   1000    1600
name8   1000    4100
name9   1000    6800
name10  800 2000
name11  700 2800
name12  700 6900
name13  700 2100
name14  500 5400
name15  400 1300
name16  400 0"

 df<- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)

    attach(df)
df<-df[order(-Distance),]
detach(df)

# df <- as.data.frame(df, stringsAsFactors = F)
p <- list()

# Set line widths
innerwidth <- 10
outerwidth <- 25

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){

  attach(df[i,])

  p[[i]] <-

    plot_ly() %>%
    add_segments(x = 0,
                 xend = as.numeric(Office),
                 y = Name,
                 yend = Name,
                 name = "Office",
                 mode = 'text',
                 text = rownames(Office),
                 hoverinfo = "x",
                 line = list(color = "#eeeeee", width = outerwidth)) %>%

    add_segments(x = 0,
                 xend = as.numeric(Distance),
                 y = Name,
                 yend = Name,
                 name = "Distance",
                 mode = 'markers+text',
                 text = ~Distance,
                 textposition = 'auto',
                 hoverinfo = "x",
                 line = list(color = "#b0c4de", width = innerwidth)) %>%

     layout(showlegend = F,
           xaxis = list(Name = "", showgrid = F, 
                        range = c(0, 7000),
                        showticklabels = FALSE,
                        showline = FALSE,
                        ticklen = 0,
                        tickfont = list(family = "Arial", size = 10),
                        tickcolor = "#cccccc"))

  detach(df[i,])
}

pp <- subplot(p[[1]], p[[2]], p[[3]], p[[4]], 
              p[[5]], p[[6]], p[[7]], p[[8]],
              p[[9]], p[[10]],p[[11]],p[[12]],
              p[[13]], p[[14]], p[[15]],
              p[[16]],
              nrows = 17,
              margin = c(0, 0, 0,0))

pp
```

Comment: Can you make your example code reproducible by linking to the data `Projects.xlsx`? Or perhaps a subset of it?